# Google Maps Javascript API client side billing

Tags: google-maps

According to the Google Maps Javascript API [billing documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage-and-billing) each new map created with the `google.maps.Map()` costs '0.007 USD' (at the time of writing). As this code is executed on the client, if a client runs `while(1) { new google.maps.Map(); }`, or equivalent, would that incur charges until stopped by the google maps console per user / global quota?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage-and-billing#dynamic-maps), Maps JavaScript API is billed per **map load** and map loads are generated every time a map is created with the **google.maps.Map()** class.

So if you have a loop that calls the google.maps.Map() class inside and creates multiple map loads, you will be billed for those generated map loads. It will only stop once your loop is stopped or if you have reached the maximum number of requests per day(QPD) which initially is set to **unlimited**. So make sure that your implementation is [optimized](https://developers.google.com/maps/optimization-guide#consumption_optimization) to avoid unnecessary charges.

If you still need further clarifications with this, feel free to [contact Google Maps Platform support](https://developers.google.com/maps/support#contact-maps-support).